# css float: right is not working correctly

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm new to web development and I'm trying to replicate this website on my own.

[image: original website]

And now I'm encountering a problem.

[image]

I'm not sure why the float: left (under @media) is not correctly working. I made sure to apply box-sizing: border-box to allow the inclusion of the padding and border in an element's total width and height.

Below is my code:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    margin-top: 40px;
    background-color: #F9F9FB;
}

.container-fluid {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

h3 {
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 1px;
    width: 33.33%;
    height: 28px;
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #B59F84;

}

.row div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: #FFFFF5;
}

p {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    clear: right;
}

/********** Large devices only **********/
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-lg-1, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-lg-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-lg-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-lg-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-9 {
    width: 74.99%;
  }
  .col-lg-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Assignment Solution for Module 2</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">Our Menu</h1>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <h3>Div 1</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            </div>  

            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <h3>Div 2</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            </div>          
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <h3>Div 3</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I made sure to apply box-sizing: border-box to allow the inclusion of the padding and border in an element's total width and height.

Edit: it should be **float: left** not float: right

Comment: Is there a problem with positioning all the divs on the page or within them?

Comment: It seems you need more space to fit 3 divs in. You need smaller sizes of divs.

Comment: seems you're using css library, bootstrap? otherwise have a look at css grid, what you intend to do is easy with css grid.

Comment: @pierfarrugia im not using bootstrap as im trying this to test my learnings. I'll take a look at css grid. Thanks!

Comment: `margin: 10px;` is not taken into account  , so the last one goes to next line. ;) rewrite your width alike `width:calc(XX% - 20px);` so margin is also minded

Comment: @G-Cyrillus thanks man, using calc(xx%-20px) worked. I got a question though, I thought if you include box-sizing: border-box; it will take margin: 10px; into account? you have any idea why it is not like that?

Comment: @RenAdrian margin is not part of the box itself, so box-sizing doesn't take it into account nor search for it :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the card's width first of all. For responsiveness, go for `max-width`.
In this example, Im using [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) along with `max-with:400px` (change to your needs) for each card. With those few extra lines, your `row` will be responsive. (In my example, they are centered in the middle of the page, you can change that by playing with `justify-content`).

```
.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}
.row div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    max-width: 400px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: #FFFFF5;
}
```